# Does mootools 1.1 support request method OTHER than get and post?

Tags: javascript, ajax, request, mootools

I'm trying to do the following:

```
new Ajax('http://....', {

  method: 'delete'

}).request();
```

The request method when inspected in my php code shows that it is defaulting to POST.

Am I correct to assume that other methods outside of *get* and *post* are NOT supported?

ps. I had a quick look in the mootools src file and I can't see any mentions of delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not support anything besides 'get' and 'post'.

http://docs111.mootools.net/Remote/XHR.js

Comment: Bummer. Bummer. Bummer. I read the docs for Ajax.js and there was no specific mention of the limitation. I should've browsed over to XHR.js too :) Thanks

Comment: I'd say you could try to extract an ajax function from another js library. But here are the notes from jQuery: "Note: Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used here, but they are not supported by all browsers."

Comment: well, 1.11 is a bit old. https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Docs/Request/Request.md -> seems to support get, post, delete, put now. having said that, the github doc differs from the one that's parsed on the mootools help pages. best ask cpojer on irc.

Comment: Dimitar, i suppose those docs are for the 1.2/1.3? In that case i've seen examples of someone having delete to work eg. http://coab.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/invoking-the-delete-verb-with-the-request-class/

Comment: Phil, a bit more reading suggests that the only common thread is get/post both in the client and server. I might stick to that.

Comment: Starting to hit some of the limitations of mootools 1.1 I'm seriously considering upgrading though. Damn legacy stuff

Comment: Definitely upgrade -- they have a helper script / compatibility layer to help. Also, some web APIs let you POST with a parameter `_method=DELETE`. See Twitter http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554696/Twitter-REST-API-Method:-DELETE-list-id

Comment: you should upgrade - get fakedarren's upgrade helper - it helped me upgrade over 15k lines of 1.11 code to 1.2.5 just fine - https://github.com/fakedarren/mootools-upgrade-helper or use my compat layer of the above http://cdn.webtogs.com/js/upgrade-helper.js (disable the commented console line at top to get started so you see the warnings about old code). Running it as a compat layer can let you run 1.1x code under 1.2.4+ w/o problems. at the very least, upgrade to 1.12 which does _some_ fixes to do with new browsers and breaking code (bind etc, look at changelog).

Comment: Yep... and once you've successfully updated to 1.25 just go ahead and upgrade to 1.3 with the latest round on capability layers. (Or move to jQuery...)